# Are there any guidelines for using the auto focus (programmatic focus) on a webpage by WCAG 2.0?

Tags: website-design, forms, user-expectation, input-focus, autofocus

Regarding ADA compliance and web accessibility guidelines like WCAG and WAI-ARIA, is there a specific requirement recommending the auto-focusing of input fields after service failure error (not a field validation error)?

Comment: This contains three types of questions: About accessibility guidelines for auto-focus, about it’s usefulness and about implementation. Can you split these up to ask one type of question at a time? Also consider reading the help center because opinion-oriented and implementation questions are not allowed.

Comment: Hi @jazZRo , I have updated the question. I would appreciate it if you can share some thoughts on it now.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't specifically, but you could potentiually be violating some standards, like 3.2.1: https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-receive-focus.html.
That said, this case depends on the circumnstances completely. For example, google does autofocus cause the input is the only important thing on the page. The problem comes when there's more to the page.If you have a page full of stuff and you want to autofocus something I would say it's bad practice.
But if it's the only interactive element on the page or the main thing you expect, as it happens in google, then be cautious but you should be fine.